# Read-only Combobox with ZK Framework

Tags: javascript, zk

Why the Combobox components, when read only, don't allows the user select a option with the Page Down\Page Up keys? How to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, what version of ZK are you using? A readonly textbox in both the latest version 5.0 and 3.6.3 both allow this.

```
<textbox value="Hello"  Readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Zk Fiddle Combobox](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1i2kjl3/38-Client-side-get-the-value-of-combobox-with-read-only)

It is working fine with

> readonly="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can use up and down arrow keys yo select an option in Combobox.